# To calculate $E(Y|X)$ and Var$(Y|X)$.

Tags: normal-distribution, expectation

Suppose $U $ and $V$ are independent and each is distributed as $ N(0,1$). Define $ X$ and $Y$ by $Y=X-1-U$,$ X=2Y-3-V$ . What is $E(Y|X)$ and  Var$(Y|X)$ ?

Again another questions which I'm unsure about.

I know the formula of $E(Y|X)$ and $Var (Y|X)$ if $f(x,y)$ is a bivariate normal distribution but I have a feeling I can't assume that here.

So would I have to do a transform of variables to get the answer? When I did so, I have trouble doing the integration of $f(x,y)$ to find the marginal density $f(x)$.

Comment: Did you write down (X,Y) in terms of (U,V)? This is the start, obviously...

Comment: I did, with Y as 4+V+U and X=V+2U+5

Comment: This should be in the question. And now, what is stopping you?

Comment: There's nothing really stopping me, I know if X,Y is a bivariate normal distribution then I can find the conditional expectation and variance easily. I'm concerned if X,Y can really be considered bivariate normal.

Comment: Well, if that is so, somebody needs to go through their notes about gaussian vectors once again: (X,Y) is an affine transform of the gaussian vector (U,V), hence...

Comment: This might be a bad time to mention that nowhere in my education I learnt about gaussian vectors.

Comment: Hmmm... Then how are you managing them? By intuition?? The WP page might be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks I'll start reading them. And to be honest kinda? I'm studying economics and there were only one mandatory maths course which is only a semester long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(U,V)$ is bivariate normal, and $(X,Y)$ is obtained from that by an affine transformation, so $(X,Y)$ is also bivariate normal.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is surprisingly the first time I heard about affine transformation.